# Favicon not being displayed at all

Tags: html, css, favicon

For some reason the favicon I generated is not appearing. I placed the favicon in the root directory of my site and I'm currently running it on a local host. Here is the code I used:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please try to open it as localhost/favicon.ico and see it appers

Comment: Where is it not appearing?

Comment: It is not appearing in the tab at the top of the page.  It wont show up when I go to localhost/favicon either.

Comment: Some browsers have restrictions on the maximum width and height of favicon. Try to reduce it to 32x32.

Comment: place the favicon.ico file directly into public_html

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. For some reason the local host was not recognizing .ico as a valid extension so I had to manually add the extension into the server code myself.

Comment: Do you mean you had to add a MIME type for .ico files?

Comment: For a proper answer worthy of an upvote, I would expect to see a brief instruction on which MIME type you added to the web server (which you haven't mentioned yet) and in what file or setting ;)